# Has `filter()` changed between Python 2.x and 3.x?

Tags: python, string, filter, anonymous-function

I tried many different examples for `filter()` with anonymous functions, but always get strange results as long as I use it on strings. Below is an example:

```
>>>print(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), "aas30dsa20"))
<filter object at 0x00000000035DE470>
```

If not strings, everything works fine. Eg;

```
>>> print(list(filter(lambda x: x >= 30 and x <= 70, [x**2 for x in range(1,11)])))
[36, 49, 64]
```

By the way, if I remove the `list()` function part, the problem similar to string case appears:

```
>>> print(filter(lambda x: x >= 30 and x <= 70, [x**2 for x in range(1,11)]))
<filter object at 0x00000000037BFDD8>
```

I am using Python 3.4.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: In a word: [yes](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Several functional tools (most notably `filter()` and `map()`) were changed to return iterators instead of sequences for 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, the filter() function returned a list, the result of filtering a sequence through a function that returned True or False for each item in the sequence. In Python 3, the filter() function returns an iterator, not a list.
Source: [diveintopython3.net](http://www.diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#filter)

[2to3 tool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) will in some cases place a list() call around the call to filter() to ensure that the result is still a list. If you need code that runs in both Python 2 and Python 3 without 2to3 conversion and you need the result to be a list, you can do the same.